# 2 argument function calls in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, arguments

I am trying to write a two argument function in bash. here is the code

```
cd() {  
if [ $1 != .. ]; then builtin cd $1 ; ls
else 
  if [ -z "$2" ]; then 
        builtin cd ..
  else
    echo "$2"
    int= $2
    while [ $int > 0 ]; do
      builtin cd ..
      ((int=int-1))
    done 
  fi ;
fi ; 
 }
```

when i run it in terminal with this line cd .. 4 it will cd the parent and echo 4 but then it prints 4: command not found. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: `int= $2 => int=$2`

Comment: See [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) And you can use `if->elif->else` instead of `if->else->if->else`. And `>` is for strings use `-gt`

Comment: Yes, that simple.  Spacing is quite often quite critical in shell scripts.  (I have a script called `4` to print input in 4 columns — I would get a hung process rather than 'command not found'.)